# How to write a DSL that creates a function with arguments?

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming, dsl

I would like to define a macro such that I can pass a `do` block into it, and have the macro create a function that calls the block, **with an argument**. I am running into a chicken & egg issue because the code below complains that `name` is not defined.

```
defmodule MyMacro do
  defmacro greet(do: block) do
    quote do
      def hello(name), do: unquote(block)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  import MyMacro
  greet do
    IO.puts("Hello, #{name}!")
  end
end
```

Attempting to compile this code results in:

```
(CompileError) iex:6: undefined function name/0
(stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
(iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:250: IEx.Evaluator.handle_eval/5
```

From my understanding, this blows up even before it gets to my macro because elixir attempts to generate an AST for the do block before calling my macro, but `name` is undefined.

My goal is to be able to call `Test.hello("world")` after compiling the DSL. Is that possible in Elixir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elixir's macros are [hygienic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro) so if you declare a variable in a macro's `quote`, it won't be available to the caller. You can disable this by wrapping the declaration of the variable with `var!`:

```
quote do
  def hello(var!(name)), do: unquote(block)
end
```

Comment: Thank you I was pulling my hair out over this